# Selector which change button padding if it has an icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, font-awesome

I am using Font Awesome icon with Bootstrap button classes and some CSS to create circle buttons: [check my CSSDesk](http://cssdeck.com/labs/bootstrap-font-awesome-circle-buttons). I moved from default Bootstrap to [Bootswatch Paper](https://bootswatch.com/paper/) and I had to override paddings:

```
td > .btn-sm.btn-circle {
padding: 6px 12px !important;
}
```

To force the same behavior like in my CSSDesk. But when I want to use `fa-user-plus` icon I found that this icon is wider than others, and then buttons is like ellipse not like circle and I need to override right padding with new value. Can I achieve it with CSS selector which change buttons only if it has child with `fa-user-plus` class? Something like this:

```
td > .btn-sm.btn-circle:with-child(.fa-user-plus) {...}
```

Is in CSS a way to do something like this? Thank you in advance for spending time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge there is no :with-child type selector in css. What you could do is use javascript to determine if .btn-sm.btn-circle has the child .fa-user-plus and then add a new class to .btn-sm.btn-circle. Then use css to generate your style as such:

```
td > .btn-sm.btn-circle.has-fa-user-plus {/*do stuff*/}
```